# Cardinalidade Minima e Cardinalidade Máxima em Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, cardinalidade

Boa Tarde!

Eu estou tentando entender sobre `Cardinalidade Minima` e `Cardinalidade Máxima` entre entidades diferentes!

O que eu sei até agora é :

> `A Cardinalidade Minima` pode ser um `Atributo Opcional(0)` ou um `Atributo Obrigatório(1)`
>
> `A Cardinalidade Máxima` pode ser um `Atributo Monovalorado(1)` ou `Atributo Multivalorado(N)`

Minha dúvida é, como irei determinar a cardinalidade dos atributos?

Será a partir das relações entre os dois atributos(por exemplo A e B) para ambas as cardinalidades?

Ou na cardinalidade minima eu tenho que ver se o atributo é obrigatório ou não, e na máxima tenho que ver quantos atributos de A se Relacionam com quantos atributos de B e quantos atributos de B se relacionam com os atributos de A?

Comment: Um-pra-um, um-para-muitos, muitos-para-muitos. Uma pessoa pode ter 0-n filhos. Uma pessoa pode ser casada com 0-1 pessoas, 1-n fornecedores podem fornecer p/ 1-m empresas

Comment: Jean,a minha duvida não é essa infelismente! Sobre os tipo de cardinalidades eu entendi, a minha duvida é como eu faço para através de um exercício ou de dados fornecidos conseguir identificar se: é obrigatória ou opcional na minima e se é multi ou mono na máxima!

Comment: infeli**z**mente isso depende caso-a-caso e pode ser ditado pelos requisitos do sistema. Exemplo: Numa tabela de pais de alunos cada pai vai ter pelo menos um filho enquanto que numa tabela de pessoas cada uma pode ter ou não filhos

Comment: então so saberei como classificar de acordo com o caso que tiver em mãos ne?

Comment: Em relação a bando de dados a resposta, 99,9% das vezes, começa por: depende...

Comment: obrigada jean!!